# Highstock ignores timestamp after data is inserted in chart

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a highstock showing some info that I gather through a REST api, and the information is all correct. Everything fine until here. The problem is, there's no data to show between 19:00 and 05:00, and I'd like that data abscence to appear in the graphic without the time span being cropped out of the xAxis, as you can see in the example.

[Time cropped there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLW6W.png)

My options are defined this way.

```
    public chartStock = {
    rangeSelector: {
      selected: 1
    },
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    series: [],
    plotOptions: {
        line: {
            connectNulls: true
        },     
        series: {
            connectNulls: true,
            dataLabels: {
                crop: false
            }
        }
    },
    xAxis: [{
        endOnTick: false
    }]
};
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I actually made it work, but it was not what I exactly wanted, since the amount of data I'm using might be too much for it in some time. I changed the chart, and I used a highchart instead of a highstock in the HTML. The configuration parameters were all okay nonetheless.